# Reversible merge

Tags: list, prolog

We can merge two sorted lists as follows

```
merge_([A|T], [], [A|T]).
merge_([], [A|T], [A|T]).
merge_([A|T], [B|U], [A|V]) :- A @< B, merge_(T, [B|U], V).
merge_([A|T], [B|U], [B|V]) :- A @>= B, merge_([A|T], U, V).
```

which works fine in one direction. What doesn't work for this definition are queries like following `merge_(A, [a, b, c], [a, b, c, d]).`, although there's unique and quite obvious solution `A = [d].`. Even iterating over `merge_(A, B, [a, b, c]).` should produce fairly trivial set of results: `A` being ordered subset of `[a, b, c]` and `B = [a, b, c] \ A`.

How do I change the definition of `merge_` to make it work in all directions?

Comment: The answer you accepted requires that the list elements be numeric. Do you require this to work with general atomic elements?

Comment: I would love to use generic atomic elements, but for now I am quite happy to understand what the problem is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@mat's answer is spot-on. When confining the problem to integers, you have the benefit of the CLP(FD) operators since they have knowledge of the domain (or "universe of possible values").

Unfortunately, `A @< B` has no way *a priori* to know what the possible values are for `A` and `B` are and, therefore, can "propose" no possible solution. If, for example, you had a predicate `valid(X)` that was true for `X` in the domain of possible values, you could write, `valid(A), valid(B), A @< B, ...`. Here's a contrived example that shows how this could work if you know what the finite domain of possible atoms that you care about.

```
    valid(X) :- member(X, [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n]).

    merge_([A|T], [], [A|T]).
    merge_([], [A|T], [A|T]).
    merge_([A|T], [B|U], [A|V]) :- valid(A), valid(B), A @< B, merge_(T, [B|U], V).
    merge_([A|T], [B|U], [B|V]) :- valid(A), valid(B), A @>= B, merge_([A|T], U, V).
```

Now that we've constrained `A` and `B` to exist in a particular finite domain of values, your predicate can work "in reverse":

```
| ?- merge_(A, [a, b, c], [a, b, c, d]).

A = [d] ? a

no
| ?- merge_(A, B, [a, b, c]).

A = [a,b,c]
B = [] ? a

A = []
B = [a,b,c]

A = [a]
B = [b,c]

A = [a,c]
B = [b]

A = [a,b]
B = [c]

A = [b,c]
B = [a]

A = [b]
B = [a,c]

A = [c]
B = [a,b]

no
| ?-
```

Answer (score 4):

The predicates `(@<)/2` and `(@>=)/2` are **not monotonic**, and as such do not exhibit the properties that are necessary to correctly describe what "merging" means in general. Programs that use such predicates may work in particular instances, but will typically yield *incorrect* results in general.

To show you the essence of the problem, the following important declarative property is violated by these predicates:

> **Adding** a goal can at most *reduce*, never extend, the set of solutions.

This *monotonicity* is broken by these properties, as illustrated for example with:

```
?- Y @< X.
false.
```

**No solution exists**, yes? In particular, *certainly* `X=1`, `Y=0` is **not** a solution, right? Well let's see:

```
?- X=1, Y=0, Y @< X.
X = 1,
Y = 0.
```

*Whaaat?* We were just told that there is *no solution whatsoever*!

In other words, we simply cannot apply even the most fundamental logical reasoning when working with these predicates. In my view, it is therefore best to avoid such predicates if you want to enjoy the benefits of logic programming to their fullest potential.

**Constraints** provide a way out of this mess. Constraints work correctly in all instantiation patterns, and allow for more general programs that work in all directions.

Here is a program that describes such merging of lists of **integers**, using **CLP(FD)** constraints:

```
merge_([A|T], [], [A|T]).
merge_([], [A|T], [A|T]).
merge_([A|T], [B|U], [A|V]) :- A #< B, merge_(T, [B|U], V).
merge_([A|T], [B|U], [B|V]) :- A #>= B, merge_([A|T], U, V).
```

The integer analogon of the example you cite:

```
?- merge_(A, [1,2,3], [1,2,3,4]).
A = [4].
```

So, this works exactly as expected. The only drawback: It requires that we map the entitites we want to reason about to *integers*. In practice, very many programs do reason over integers in any case, so that is often acceptable.

Similar generalizations are possible also for other domains. However, integers are among the most commonly used domains, and all widely used Prolog systems therefore ship with CLP(FD) constraints which I recommend as a useful starting point or even solution for such issues.

By the way, the other example you cite also works completely as expected if you simply use CLP(FD) constraints:

```
?- merge_(A, B, [1,2,3]).
A = [1, 2, 3],
B = [] ;
A = [],
B = [1, 2, 3] ;
A = [1],
B = [2, 3] ;
A = [1, 2],
B = [3] ;
etc.
```